# Showing a specific tab after page reload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's the initial state of my tabs:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTabTabs">
<li class="active"><a href="#details" data-toggle="tab">Details</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#publishing" data-toggle="tab">Publishing</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#process-1" data-toggle="tab">Process: 1</a></li>
<li class=""><a href="#process-2" data-toggle="tab">Process: 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

So far I figured out how to remove the active class from all the li tags:

```
(function($) {

  $(window).load(function() {

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event) {
       $(this).closest('.nav').find('.active').removeClass('active');
     }); 
  });

})(jQuery);
```

But I can't figure how to show a specific tab afterward.
I tried the following:

```
$('.nav-tabs a[href="#process-1"]').tab('show');
```

but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me with this one ?

Thanks

Comment: When clicking on a tab it will add the hash to the url I am assuming. So you could on load read it from the URL like this `window.location.hash` From there it is easy, I would just simulate a click on the correct tab

Comment: `window.location.hash` doesn't work here. On the other hand `event.target.hash` does.
What should I do from there ? Should I modify the hash ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I made you a jsfiddle to explain what I do, but the jsfiddle won't show you the reload - you have to copy the code into a file.

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/18024/

Since bootstrap kindly prevents the href from setting your hash on click you have to add it yourself. Then all you need to do is fetch it again when the page loads and "click" on the right tab.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" aria-controls="nav-home">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-profile" aria-controls="nav-profile">Profile</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" aria-controls="nav-contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">home</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">profile</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-contact-tab">contact</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$(function() {
    $('#nav-tab a').click(function(){
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr('aria-controls');
    });

    $('[href="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');
});
```

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/

Comment: Thank you very much for the jsfiddle.
Your code doesn't exactly behave as I expect but it put me on the right track.
After some modifications here's the code which work with my html tabs above:

`(function($) { 

$(window).load(function() {

  $('#myTabTabs li a').click(function(){
     window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');
  });

  var hash = '#process-1'; //Just as an example.

  $('[href="'+hash+'"]').trigger('click');
})(jQuery);`

To be honest I'm not 100% sure of what happens here, but whatever works.

Comment: @Duddy67 So what you are doing is you are saying that if the tab gets clicked, your url will append the #whatever location so that when you reload you can fetch the last position again and simulate a click on where it should be. An alternative method is to use localstorage to save page preferences rather than in the url. All depends on what works best for you. I am sure this is not best practice but it feels clean to me.